# How to activate my camera aperture and speed wheels

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, aperture-priority

I have a Nikon d7000 and I often shoot in Aperture mode.
Sometimes, when I turn the aperture wheel, the aperture doesn't change. I have to mid-press the shutter button and then only, I can change the aperture.

Is it normal? How to avoid this behaviour (like if the camera was entering into a kind of "sleeping mode")?

Thank for your answers

PS: I looked in the manual but didn't find something related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

Assuming that this works the same on the D7000 as the D7100, search the manual for "standby timer". The c2 custom setting (on the D7100) controls for how long the settings can be changed after a half-press of the shutter button.  The default is 6 seconds.  You can increase this or set it to "no limit".

Quoting the manual:

> The Standby Timer
>
> The viewfinder and the control panel shutter speed
>   and aperture displays will turn off if no operations are performed for
>   about 6 seconds, reducing the drain on the battery. Press the
>   shutter-release button halfway to reactivate the display. The length
>   of time before the standby timer expires automatically can be selected
>   using Custom Setting c2

Turning on the top LCD backlight also activates the timer.